# Issues using own library in other project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have updated a library I own and have seemingly broken something when using it within another project, but I cannot understand why this is the case.

I have a myriad of error logs of a similar type being displayed:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@company-name/lib-name/dist/component/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@company-name/another-owned-lib/dist' in '/Users/username/new-project/node_modules/@company-name/lib-name/dist/component'
Did you mean 'index.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request '@company-name/another-owned-lib/dist' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
```

Within this error you will notice 3 different repos mentioned:

- **new-project**: This is the new repo I am creating
- **owned-lib**: This is the library repo I have just updated and imported into **new-project**
- **another-owned-lib**: This is another of my owned libs that is used within both **owned-lib** and **new-project** - for clarity, I haven't made any changes to this.

---

### owned-lib

An update I made within this repo was to add `"type": "module"` to the `package.json`.

**package.json (redacted)**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@mui/material": "^5.xx.x",
        "@company-name/another-owned-lib": "^x.x.x",
        "@types/react": "^18.x.x",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.x.x",
        "jest": "^29.x.x",
        "react": "^18.x.x",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "ts-jest": "^29.x.x",
        "tss-react": "^4.x.x"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.x.x",
        "@types/jest": "^29.x.x",
        "babel-loader": "^8.x.x",
        "typescript": "^5.x.x"
    },
    "files": ["dist"],
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "type": "module",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts"
}
```

**ts-config.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "declaration": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable",
            "esnext"
        ],
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "rootDirs": [
            "src",
            "stories"
        ],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "target": "esnext"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "src/**/*.test.*"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

---

### new-project

**package.json (redacted)**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@mui/material": "^5.xx.x",
        "@company-name/another-owned-lib": "^2.xx.x",
        "react": "^18.xx.x",
        "react-dom": "^18.xx.x",
        "react-scripts": "^5.xx.x",
        "typescript": "^4.xx.x"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.xx.x",
        "@types/jest": "^29.xx.x",
        "@types/node": "^18.xx.x",
        "@types/react": "^18.xx.x",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.xx.x",
        "jest": "^29.xx.x",
        "ts-jest": "^29.xx.x",
        "webpack": "^5.xx.x"
    }
}
```

**ts-config.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable",
            "esnext"
        ],
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": false,
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "include": [
        "src"
    ]
}
```

---

A last FYI - The 'another-owned-lib' repo also has `"type": "module"` within its `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

As explained in your error, if you are using esm (which you did by using `type: module` in your `package.json`), then you need extension in your import statement, when you are importing that package.

> A file extension must be provided when using the import keyword to resolve relative or absolute specifiers. Directory indexes (e.g. './startup/index.js') must also be fully specified.
>
> This behavior matches how import behaves in browser environments, assuming a typically configured server.
> https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions

Meaning, you cannot use `import '@abc/xyz'`. You'll have to use

```
import '@abc/xyz/index.js'; // or
import '@abc/xyz/index.mjs';
```

---

On a side note, this "issue" is already handled if you use TypeScript (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html).

So my preference is to write the UI library in TypeScript, then bundle it using `vite` (or maybe `rollup`) and then generate bundle for both `cjs` and `esm` versions.

In my `package.json`, I'll have `main`, `module` and `types` keys set.

Comment: I am using TS in all of the mentioned repos, which is why I'm a bit confused. I will have a look at using Vite to bundle as I know the one I haven't touched does use this, so this might be the problem.